# Transmission want shifted into 3rd or overdrive . It's in a 99 chevy z71 5.3 engine was low on fluid i filled it up still only has 1st and 2nd

Tags: chevrolet, automatic-transmission, silverado

Transmission was low on fluid so I think  it got hot . I put some Lucas in it and it did change any is there a way to fix it with rebuild it

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!